# delete_if is not working with array.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to delete certain elements from an array with .delete_if. For example, I want the following removed from the array

> [83] #["CN=hhtest,OU=Users XXX,DC=XXX,DC=com"],
>   :cn=>["hhtest"], :sn=>["test"], :givenname=>["hh"],
>   :memberof=>["CN=SSLVPN-Users,CN=Users,DC=XXX,DC=com",
>   "CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=XXX,DC=com"],
>   :userprincipalname=>["hhtest@XXX.com"]}> ] ]

I am trying to delete that with

```
  @ldap_result.delete_if { |cn| cn == 'hhtest' }
```

I've tried other variations as well.  Note - if I do a @ldap_result.class in my view, it returns `array'

If I do

`@ldap_result.delete_if { |cn| cn != 'hhtest' }`

I end up with an empty array which seems counterintuitive.

Comment: what is @ldap_result? That unformated stuff in the orange box looks more like a hash

Comment: Does `cn[0] == 'httest'` work?

Comment: delete_if() iterates elements and you're trying to match elements against plain string 'hhtest'. It seems you should go one level deeper i.e.:   @ldap_result.delete_if { |el| el[:cn] == 'hhtest' }

Answer (score 0):

The comments to my question got me thinking I was on the wrong track. I ended up not using the delete_if at all. What I did was to walk through the list of names I pulled directly from ldap and then check to see if there is a matching entry in the ldap_exceptions table. I know this isn't very efficient but we have 100 users at most to walk through and only 3 or 4 people will be using the app at any one time.

```
  # ---------------------------------
    # this is where we build the operator list. The operator list is the users pulled from LDAP minus any user
    # names entered in the ldap exceptions table. Note - Case and spacing must match exactly with the users
    # you want to exclude.

    @ldap_exceptions = LdapException.all                                      # get all of the users in ldap exceptions.

    @operator_list = ["x"]                                                    # initialize @operator_list as an array.


    @ldap_names.each do |ldn|                                                 # ldap names comes from the application controller.
        @ldap_exception = LdapException.where("username like ?", ldn)         # See if there is an entry in the ldap exception table. This isn't very efficient but considering the number of ldap users,
                                                                              # it should be fine.
        if !@ldap_exception.present? then                                     # if the ldap user isn't in the ldap exceptions table write it to the array
            @operator_list = @operator_list + [ldn]                           # ldn has to be in [] or you get a string into an array error.
        end
    end
```

In short, I was trying to do a delete_if on something that was a hash, not an array. This method works.